# I need help instantiating multiple objects from a single method & class

Tags: c#, instantiation

C# HOMEWORK QUESTION: I am creating a console application that prompts for two integers, prompts for which math operation to perform, and returns the results. I was able to get it to work with my two operands hardcoded, and now I'm trying to instantiate two separate objects through user input instead of a hardcoded variable. I've stripped it down to the barebones code that I'm having issues with, and I suspect the problem has something to do with the way I'm creating two objects from the same method...but I'm not sure what.

Here's my main class...

```
 public class MainModule 
 {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         // get Operands
        Console.WriteLine("You Will Be Entering Two Integers.\n");
         //
        MathUI myOperand1 = new MathUI();
        int op1 = myOperand1.EnterInteger();
         //
        MathUI myOperand2 = new MathUI();
        int op2 = myOperand2.EnterInteger();

        Console.WriteLine("You chose {0} and {1}.", (int)op1, (int)op2);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
 }
```

...and the MathUI class that accepts inputs.

```
public class MathUI
{
    public int EnterInteger()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter an integer: ");
        int enteredInteger = Console.Read();
        return (enteredInteger);
    }
}
```

When I execute the program, I get a prompt for an integer. I enter, for instance, 3, here's my output.

```
You Will Be Entering Two Integers.

Enter an integer: 3
Enter an integer: You chose 51 and 13.

Math demo completed
Press <enter> to quit
```

When I press enter after entering the first integer, I automatically get a second integer; and when I try to output the integer values, they don't match my input.

What's going on here? Is there something wrong with the way that I'm instantiating `MathUI` and my two operands? Do I only need to instantiate one instance of `MathUI` then declare both variables under that one instance? I'm also not sure why the integer output does not match my input. All the variables are cast as `int`, so I should have `int` all the way through, right? I tried casting these as integers--`(int)op1`--just in case `op1` was held in some internal form...but don't know what's going on there.

What am I missing?

Comment: nothing to do with objects, everything to do with `Console.Read` use `ReadLine()` instead, that way it stops reading after you press the `Enter` key

Comment: also you can instantiate one object from `MathUI` and call `EnterInteger()` twice

Comment: a) why instantiate two MathUI instead of one if the operand is not a field of the object? b) use ReadLine() c) use int.Parse(x)

Comment: @AmirIsmail - i was wondering if that was possible; thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you are using [`Console.Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx) method which returns a value after any key has been pressed. Also, result it returns is [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters) value of key pressed. In your case, you pressed <kbd>3</kbd> which has ordinal (ASCII) value of 51 in decimal system and then <kbd>ENTER</kbd> which has value 13. If you look at MSDN documentation, `Console.Read` returns an integer.

To read value user entered as a string, use [`Console.ReadLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline.aspx) method.

If you really need to read in key by key, you can use [`Convert.ToChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/609e20th.aspx), and then `ToString` method to get entered key as string. Like so:

```
string key = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine()).ToString();
```

Or you can use following code to read actual operand

```
int intOperand;
if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out intOperant))
    Console.WriteLine("You pressed non-numeric key");
```

---

Answer (score 3):

you need to make the Console.Read a Console.ReadLine as readline is triggered by the return key.

```
public class MathUI
{
    public int EnterInteger()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter an integer: ");
        int enteredInteger = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        return (enteredInteger);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Console.Readline` returns a string. You need to parse the string to an `int`.

Comment: made the conversion using Convert.ToInt32

Comment: i'll give you a +1 to cancel out the -1

Answer (score 1):

Use `Console.ReadLine` instead of `Console.Read`. With `Console.Read`, the return character is being passed as input to the second `Read` call.

Also note that the int that is returned by `Console.Read` is not parsing a numeric number, it is giving you the Unicode character value of the entered char. This is why you are getting the "wrong" numbers.

You need to use `Console.ReadLine` and parse the string result like so:

```
        public class MathUI
        {
            public int EnterInteger()
            {
                Console.Write("Enter an integer: ");
                int enteredInteger = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                return (enteredInteger);
            }
        }
```

A couple other notes for your consideration:

- There's no need to cast the values in the `Console.WriteLine` call.
- You can make the `MathUI` class and `EnterInteger` method static.

Comment: It's not UTF-8, but UTF-16 (just like all characters in .Net). And calling that encoding “Unicode” is mostly true, but confusing (and the fact that Microsoft does it too doesn't change that).

Comment: @svick: Yep that was a typo. Not that it matters for 0-9 digits.